# how can I get a datalist contents after adding them via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datalist

I have an input field with datalist options, which has it's suggestions updated via AJAX after chhange of other field.

I tried to add new options to the datalist as other questions proposed:

```html
$("#add_option").change(function(){
   var _opt_opt_name_val = $(this).val();
   var opt_name_url=_url+"?opt_name="+escape(_opt_opt_name_val);
   var _values_datalist_id = $("#opt_values").attr("list")
   var _value_html = "";
   $.get(opt_name_url,function(data){
       $(_values_datalist_id).empty();
       $.each(data, function(key, v){
           _value_html += '<option value="' + v.value + '"></option>';
       });
       $(_values_datalist_id).append(_value_html);
       console.log("added code: "+$(_values_datalist_id).html());
   });
});
```

As it didn't work, I'd like to check (read) what was appended via this javascript. tried $("#element").text() and .html(). Both return *undefined*.

How could I retrieve the datalist contents in this (or any) case? For debugging, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Again, after 3 days fiddling with this problem, I had an insight for doing it:

I mixed JQuery for the Ajax part and Vanilla Javascript for adding the new options. Not much elegant, but worked so far:

```
$("#add_option").change(function(){
    var _opt_opt_name_val = $(this).val();
    var opt_name_url=_url+"?opt_name="+escape(_opt_opt_name_val);
    var _values_datalist_id = $("#opt_values").attr("list")
    $.get(opt_name_url,function(data){
        var _datalist=document.getElementById(_values_datalist_id);
        _datalist.innerHTML = "";
        $.each(data, function(key, v){
            _datalist.innerHTML += '<option value="' + v.value + '"></option>';
        });
    });
});
```

and this solved my present problem today. Maybe this can help anyone with a similar problem? (I still don't know how to get the datalist options via jQuery though).